# Match whitespace plus = or = is first char

Tags: python, regex

I was getting quite far via regex101 but now I am stuck.

I want to extract a string between "markers" using Regex from Python 3.9.
In the following example lines I will get the `foobar` back for each line. The "marker" is `=`. But that marker does have some edge cases.

1. `lore =foobar= ipsum` (there is space before and after `=`)
2. `lore =foobar=.`
3. `=foobar= ipsum`
4. `lore =foobar=`

This is what shouldn't **not match** because the `=x` is not allowed.

5. `lore =foobar=x`

That is the regex I am using (Python 3.9)

`=(.*?)=[ .]` (see a space in the beginning!)

I can handle the characters following after the second marker; allowed is a space or a period.

Number 1 and 2 are working. But 3 and 4 are missing.

The *no character* or *line ending* is missing.

Also in the beginning I don't now how to check for *no character before `=` OR*  .

Comment: `=(.*?)=[ .]?` works for me on all 4 of your examples. The final `?` just makes the character following the second `=` optional. Although, why don't you just use `=(.*?)=`?

Comment: using lookahead, `\s=.+=(?=[.\s]?)` using the `?` as explained by @MattDMo

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?:^| )=(.*?)=(?:[ .]|$)` See https://regex101.com/r/1agncw/1

Comment: Sorry I added and edge case based on your comments. The solution of @Thefourthbird gives me the expected output. But I don't understand all details; e.g. `(?:` is new to me; named as _Non-capturing group_ by regex101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the pattern as:

```
(?:^| )=(.*?)=(?:[ .]|$)
```

- `(?:^| )` Non capture group with an alternation `|` matching either a space or assert the start of the string
- `=` Match literally
- `(.*?)` Capture group 1, match any character as least as possible
- `=` Match literallt
- `(?:[ .]|$)` Match either a space or dot, or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1agncw/1)

If there can not be any equals sign in between, you might also write the pattern as:

```
(?<!\S)=([^=\n]*)=(?:[ .]|$)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitspace boundary to the left
- `=` Match literally
- `([^=\n]*)` Capture group 1, match any character except `=` or a newline
- `=` Match literally
- `(?:[ .]|$)` Match either a space or dot, or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LV22wo/1)